# Is a power series uniformly convergent in its interval of convergence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

Let $R>0$ be the radius of convergence of a power series $Σa_nx^n$. Is it not uniformly convergent in $(-R,R)$? My book goes out of its way to say that if $[a,b]⊂(-R,R)$, then the power series converges uniformly in $[a,b]$. Can't we just say that it is uniformly convergent in $(-R,R)$?

Comment: This mode of convergence is sometimes called "uniform convergence on compact subsets", "local uniform convergence", or "normal convergence".  As shown below it's not the same as uniform convergence.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. Think about the geometric series, which converges (but not uniformly) to 
$$
1 + x + x^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-x}
$$
on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: This seems so obvious now that you've pointed it out. Thank you.

Comment: It's an occupational hazard among mathematicians: things often look obvious after you understand them. That doesn't mean they were obvious beforehand.

Comment: +1 for the consolation. The confusion came from the fact that we proved certain properties of a power series in $(-R,R)$, from the uniform convergence in a closed subinterval $[-R+δ,R-δ]$. For instance, the sum function of the power series is continuous on the subinterval due to uniform convergence in said subinterval. We then proceed to conclude the continuity in $(-R,R)$ since $δ$ was arbitrary. I thought if we can do this, why not use the same reasoning for uniform convergence?

Comment: Is this because continuity is a property regarding a single point whereas uniform convergence has to do with the whole interval?

Comment: @HritRoy Yes, pretty much. To be a little more technical, continuity is a property regarding values _near_ a single point, not _at_ a single point.

Comment: True. Thanks for correcting me. But pointwise convergence is also such a property. Then wouldn't the pointwise convergence in the aforementioned subinterval imply the pointwise convergence in $(-R,R)$?

Comment: Yes. The theorem you quote in a previous comment implies pointwise convergence on the whole interval (and more, as you note).

Comment: Also note that if the series converges uniformly in $(-R,R)$, then it in fact converges uniformly in $[-R,R]$, and in particular, it converges to a continuous function on $[-R,R]$. Thus, any series that does not have finite limits at the endpoints of the interval must be a counterexample.

Comment: @AnneBauval E.g., let $S_n(x)=\sum_{i\le n}a_ix^i$ denote the partial sums. Then uniform convergence in $(-R,R)$ means that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n,m\ge n_0$ and $x\in(-R,R)$, $|S_n(x)-S_m(x)|\le\epsilon$. Since the $S_n$ are continuous in $x$, this implies $|S_n(x)-S_m(x)|\le\epsilon$ for all $x\in[-R,R]$.

Comment: @AnneBauval The $S_n$ are *polynomials*. They are defined on all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Shame on me! Thank you for your patience and your quick answers.

Answer (score 13):

No. Example: $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Suppose that $s_n(x):=\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ converges uniformly on $(-1,1)$ to $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Then , to $ \epsilon=1$ we get $N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$\frac{|x|^{N+1}}{1-x}=|s_N(x)-\frac{1}{1-x}|<1$  for all $x \in (-1,1)$.

Hence $\lim_{x \to 1-}\frac{|x|^{N+1}}{1-x} \le 1$. But $\lim_{x \to 1-}\frac{|x|^{N+1}}{1-x}= \infty$, a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, of course. Silly of me. Thanks alot.