# Uniformly convergence of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I need to find in which interval this infinite series is uniformly convergent.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{x-2}{6})^n$

I can see that it converges when $-4 < x <8$ but I can't figure out when it is uniformly convergent.

Useful choices: $-3.8 < x < 7.8$ and $-4 < x < 0$.

Anyone has some ideas?

Comment: Recall that a power series is uniformly convergent within its radius of convergence...

Comment: You need to solve the inequality $|(x-2)/6| < 1$. For geometric series, there is no need to test the endpoints, either (unless instructed to do so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a power series centered at $2$

The radius of convergence is $6$

So it converges  uniformly at every compact subset of $(-4,8)$

So the only choice of the six, is the interval $[-3,8,7,8]$

Comment: Which is not one of his "choices." The question was posed poorly, in my opinion.

Comment: @Math1000 in the second intervals it is converges uniformply

Comment: Yes, but it also converges uniformly in the (larger) interval $[-3.9,7.9]$, for example. And no, it is not uniformly convergent on $-4<x<8$ (which is what I assume you meant, @JohnJohnsen).

Comment: Why is it not uniformly convergent in $-4 < x <0$ (choice 5)?

Comment: A power series is uniformly convergent on any compact set contained within its interval of convergence. It is *not* uniformly convergent on its entire interval of convergence (see here for a counterexample: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544418/is-a-power-series-uniformly-convergent-in-its-interval-of-convergence)